# Problems with error handling in Laravel API

Tags: laravel-api

I have a method for creating a community, which implies user authentication via a token, if I remove the token for the test, I get an error from laravel itself:

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException: The GET method is not supported for route api/login. Supported methods: POST. in file

Here is my method:

```
public function create(CommunityRequest $request)
{
    if (!Auth::check()) {
        return response()->json([
            "status" => "error",
            "message" => "Вы не авторизованы",
        ], 401);
    }

    if (Auth::check()) {
        $data = $request->validated();

        $data['creator_id'] = Auth::user()->id;

        $community = Community::create($data);

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Сообщество успешно создано', 'data' => $community], 201);
    }
}
```

Here is my route:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
    Route::post('/community/create', [CommunityController::class, 'create']); // Create community
});
```